# Beirut 2020 explosion vs a nuclear explosion with the same energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, nuclear-physics, explosions

Port Beirut disaster (ammonium nitrate explosion, 4 August 2020) was equivalent to 1.15 kt of TNT (4.4 TJ). It falls in the range of a small nuclear device (20 t TNT for the smallest, 15 kt TNT for Little Boy, which was dropped on Hiroshima).

What is the difference between such an explosion, and a nuclear device of a similar scale?
Ionizing radiation and nuclear fallout are obvious. But when it comes to its destructive power related to heat, pressure, range, etc - would the outcomes be equivalent?

See:

- [Largest artificial non-nuclear explosions - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_artificial_non-nuclear_explosions)
- [Beirut Blast: How does yield of 2,750 tonnes of ammonium nitrate compare against Halifax explosion, Hiroshima bombing?](https://www.dnaindia.com/world/report-beirut-blast-how-does-yield-of-2750-tonnes-of-ammonium-nitrate-compare-against-halifax-explosion-hiroshima-bombing-2836137)

Comment: My guess is that a TNT-equivalent nuclear device would produce: (1) more heat, vaporizing anything within some radius, and causing serious burns to people farther out; (2) more/brighter light, blinding anyone within some radius that happened to be viewing the explosion, which, as you can see from video footage, is not what happened in this case; and (3), it would produce ionizing radiation (including the nuclear fallout), which would be fatal, or at the least very harmful, for people within some radius.

Comment: @ThePointer: When you say "more heat, more light", but the energy is the same (kiloton TNT is really an energy measure), then what form of energy output is decreased? On an unrelated note, the "serious burns at a distance" is caused by bright light, not the heat of the explosion. Heat doesn't travel that well through air, especially not sideways. Hot air rises. In fact, the mushroom cloud is caused by cold air rushing in at low level.

Comment: @MSalters Hmm, interesting. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That fertilizer is so dangerous because an explosion of that substance is a chemical reaction that turns a solid into gas. This means that immediately after the explosion a huge amount of gas is compressed into a very small volume. Assuming a nuclear explosion with the same energy (not: the same TNT equivalent) you do not have that effect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me say that I almost started crying when I saw what happened in a country already in a miserable state. I really felt sorry for those poor people. Here in Holland, there was once a huge explosion in a firework factory, which wiped away a whole area of houses, but in Beirut that was just the trigger!
It's noticeable that the smallest A-bomb releases about the same amount of energy as released in the Beirut explosion (see [here](https://www.quora.com/How-small-can-a-nuclear-weapon-be)).
The Beirut explosion is somewhat like a "smeared out" version of the explosion of an A-bomb explosion (from here I assume an equal power yield of the explosions), except that the Beirut explosion stayed put on the ground, which absorbed more energy than in the case of an A-bomb, meaning that there is more energy left for it to cause horror, misery, and destruction.
Obviously, the energy released in the Beirut explosion originated in a much bigger volume than the small A-bomb. Because of the energy being released from a much smaller volume in an A-bomb explosion, the heat is enormous (10 000 000 Kelvin) and is the main form of energy released (about 99%, after a short flash of gamma radiation). This has the effect that the pressure on the surrounding air is enormous and causes much more damage than the shock wave in Beirut.
The intense heat fireball in an A-bomb (if just as in Beirut the explosion takes place on the ground) doesn't stay on the ground but rises up fast, causing more injuries (burning wounds). Because of this, the shock wave has more impact too.
The Beirut explosion caused of course a huge amount of destruction and people's suffering too. Most of the energy released in that case was turned into kinetic energy of the surroundings.
But comparing the two I'm sure the death and injury toll would have been much higher when an equivalent A-bomb was detonated at the place of the explosion.

Comment: Re, "...fireball...doesn't stay on the ground..." It wouldn't normally even _start_ on the ground. The blast from a nuclear weapon is almost entirely due to the rapid expansion of air that is heated by the radiation. In order to maximize the amount of heated air, and therefore, the size of the blast; most nuclear weapons are designed to be exploded thousands of feet above the ground.